# Mp3/Wav Playback in Rhomobile 5.4 on Android

Tags: android, audio, rhomobile

I have an app that attempts to play a small sound file using the following code:

```
Alert.play_file("/public/audio/" + $audio_file + ".mp3", "audio/x-mp3") if Configuration.current.audio_prompt?
```

When I use this code the app throws a "Server Error" that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried using the Media player API instead of the Alert API, and received essentially the same error.

Is this a codec issue?

For Wav files (yes the wav file is correctly pointed to instead of mp3 in those lines) the error is not thrown, but the sound itself does not play.

**EDIT**

I was finally able to get some logcat data during this error, and received this:

> 09-25 19:51:03.122  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:122 000022f4           HttpServer| GC End.
>   09-25 19:51:03.123  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:123 000022f4           HttpServer| Process URI: '/app/Animation/draw'
>   09-25 19:51:03.124  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:124 000022f4                  APP| RHO serve: /app/Animation/draw
>   09-25 19:51:03.125  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:124 000022f4                  APP| Params: {"char_id"=>"6", "ajax"=>"", "run"=>"1"}
>   09-25 19:51:03.131   500   500 V AudioFlinger: releasing 55 from 8891 for -1
>   09-25 19:51:03.131   500   500 V AudioFlinger:  decremented refcount to 0
>   09-25 19:51:03.131   500   500 V AudioFlinger: purging stale effects
>   09-25 19:51:03.132  8891  8948 E ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
>   09-25 19:51:03.132  8891  8948 D MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
>   09-25 19:51:03.132  8891  8948 E ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
>   09-25 19:51:03.132  8891  8948 D MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
>   09-25 19:51:03.132   500  4043 V AudioFlinger: acquiring 56 from 8891, for -1
>   09-25 19:51:03.132   500  4043 V AudioFlinger:  added new entry for 56
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     : E 09/25/2016 19:51:03:133 000022f4           RhoFileApi| Can not open file descriptor: /public/audio/xing4.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     : E 09/25/2016 19:51:03:133 000022f4 NotificationSingleton| null
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1133)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1118)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at com.rho.notification.NotificationSingleton.playFile(NotificationSingleton.java:168)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at com.rho.notification.NotificationSingletonBase$playFileTask.run(NotificationSingletonBase.java:106)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     :  at com.rhomobile.rhodes.api.MethodExecutor.run(MethodExecutor.java:11)
>   09-25 19:51:03.133  8891  8948 I APP     : E 09/25/2016 19:51:03:133 000022f4         MethodResult| Callback: , data: ; Tab id: -1; resultType: typeError; result: "null"
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:133 000022f4                  APP| App error: 
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     :  lib/RhoNotificationApi.rb:53:in `playFile'
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : lib/RhoNotificationApi.rb:53:in`play_file'
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : apps/app/Animation/animation_controller.rb:273:in `draw'
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : lib/rho/rhocontroller.rb:101:in`serve'
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : lib/rho/rhoapplication.rb:217:in `serve'
>   09-25 19:51:03.134  8891  8948 I APP     : lib/rho/rho.rb:836:in`serve'
>   09-25 19:51:03.135  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:135 000022f4           HttpServer| GC Start.
>   09-25 19:51:03.153  8891  8891 W cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 8891
>   09-25 19:51:03.162  8891  8891 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:162 000022bb     WebViewSingleton| onNavigateComplete <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>   09-25 19:51:03.162   721   721 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ115 from CPU0 to CPU3
>   09-25 19:51:03.244   514   628 E ThermalEngine: ==== Enter sched_bmhb_cs_gov -> vs_temp = 305 ===
>   09-25 19:51:03.250  8891  8948 I APP     : I 09/25/2016 19:51:03:250 000022f4           HttpServer| GC End.

The most relevant point it seems is the line:

RhoFileApi| Can not open file descriptor: /public/audio/xing4.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Which seems to indicate a missing file or bad location, but that is most certainly where my file resides.

I've found some posts that seem to be similar issues here:

https://developer.zebra.com/thread/4416

https://developer.zebra.com/thread/1787

But their solutions did not work. I didn't try making a folder explicitly called "alerts" as opposed to "audio" in the public folder, but I can't see why that would matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now. For those coming later, the problem was that the file location needs to be referenced from absolute position, which can be done thusly:

```
Rho::Notification.playFile( Rho::Application.appsBundleFolder + "/public/audio/" + $audio_file + ".mp3", "audio/x-mp3")
```